# php class="active" error with navbar

Tags: php, html, web

I have been looking for many ways to make a tab active on a click using PHP include function to add the navbar to each page and used PHP to make link active if clicked so here is what I have the error or problem is it displays " and a > before the word home or any other tab
so here is the code... for main navbar PHP file... This is included in the html using a PHP include function:

```
<body>


<!--Nav Bar-->
            <?php 

                function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
                {
                    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

                    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
                        echo 'class="active"';
                }

            ?>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="navbar-inner"> 
             <div class="container" >               
                    <ul class="nav">

                        <a class="brand" class="divider-vertical" href="#"> The Aerosquadron</a>                                          
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>><a href="index.php">">Home</a></li>                                             
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("Robots_page")?>><a href="Robots_page.php">">Robots</a></li>                                       
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("Sponsors_page")?>><a href="Sponsors_page.php">">Our Sponsors</a></li>    
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("History")?>><a href="History.php">The History</a></li>                                         
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("About_first")?>><a href="About_first.php">">About FIRST</a></li>

                    </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to change all the <?= tags to normal <?php tags. For as far as I know the <?= tags automatically echo the stuff you put between these tags. also, end every item in your php tag with an ';'. Example: <?php echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index");?>

Answer (score 0):

Final HTML part:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="navbar-inner"> 
             <div class="container" >
                    <ul class="nav">

                        <a class="brand" class="divider-vertical" href="#"> The Aerosquadron</a>
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>                                           
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("Robots_page")?>><a href="Robots_page.php">Robots</a></li>                             
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("Sponsors_page")?>><a href="Sponsors_page.php">Our Sponsors</a></li>    
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("History")?>><a href="History.php">The History</a></li>                                
                        <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("About_first")?>><a href="About_first.php">About FIRST</a></li>

                    </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok so i got rid of the "'s and now the > sign is still there any ideas?

Comment: In my localhost, there's no > sign. Are you sure it's still there?

Comment: i fixed that problem now the problem is it wont be active

Comment: hey if your looking at this can someone help me because it wont make the class active even though there are no more problems look wise just wont become active